# Trying to get the value of a checkbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and I am trying to fetch the value of a checkbox using attr(). But the result in the alert box says "undefined". Plz someone explain why does that happen?

```js
$("#checkbox").click(function() {
  alert($("checkbox").attr("value"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="UK">UK
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="US">USA
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="Rus">Russia
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of the issue, but ids should be unique in HTML.

Comment: I tried #checkbox and $("input[type='checkbox']") too but both of them didn't work.

Comment: `#checkbox` with your current code will only work with UK, my previous comment is not completely true see answers below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several issues here:

- `$('checkbox')` isn't a valid selector as it's searching for a `<checkbox />` element which doesn't exist. You can select the element by attribute instead, eg `[name="checkbox"]` or by using the `:checkbox` selector.
- You should use the `val()` method to get the value of a form input, not `attr('value')`
- You have multiple elements with the same `id` which is invalid. `id` must be unique within the DOM. Use classes if you want to group common elements.
- Use the `change` event on checkbox and radio inputs as it's better for accessibility (ie. it will still work for those users who navigate the web via their keyboard only)
- Use the `this` keyword within the event handler to get a reference to the element which raised the event.

With those issues in mind, this should work for you:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="UK">UK
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="US">USA
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Rus">Russia
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

ID's should be unique, so don't use them in this case. But e.g. you can select all checkboxes:

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="UK">UK
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="US">USA
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="Rus">Russia
<div id="result"></div>
```

I have also changed the inside of the alert, as `click` sets the `this` value to the affected element.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `$("checkbox")` doesn't select anything. If you changed that line to `$('#checkbox')` your code would work for the first checkbox. Also, ids in HTML should be unique. If you change id to class and change the query to be `$('.checkbox')` then you can alert with any of the check boxes.

```js
$(".checkbox").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="UK">UK
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="US">USA
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Rus">Russia
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input[type='checkbox']` to get all the checkbox input instead of trying to get them by their ids.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="UK">UK
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="US">USA
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="Rus">Russia
<div id="result"></div>
```